# Setting Empty String for Enum Value in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have an object in Java which I am trying to set from an enum class with following structure.

```
public enum Code {
    CODE_A,
    CODE_B,
    CODE_C,
    CODE_D,
    CODE_E,
    CODE_F,
    EMPTY("")
}
```

Want to set my object to empty sting value. i.e. 
**Object.setCode(Code.EMPTY)**

And when I look at my Object, it should have **""** instead of **EMPTY** as value for the property code.

Can someone suggest what's a workaround I can use ? I don't want to modify the Object.setCode setter which is as below:

```
public void setCode(Code code) {
    this.code = code;
}
```

Also the problem is Object.setCode(**MustBe of Object-Code Type only**)

Comment: override the toString method of the enum `Code`

Comment: What method of `Code` are invoked? If it's `toString()` then you can just override that. If it's `name()` then I don't think you can change that the the empty string.

Comment: As pointed out in the previous comment, how do you invoke the `Code` Enum? is it invoked in any UI as items of ComboBox or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply assign a value to each enum and override the toString() method so that calling Code.EMPTY returns the value "" instead of "EMPTY"

```
enum Code{

    CODE_A("STRING_A"),
    CODE_B("STRING_B"),
    EMPTY("");

    // Assigning a value to each enum
    private final String code;
    Code(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    // Overriding toString() method to return "" instead of "EMPTY"
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.code;
    }

}
```

So running Code.CODE_A will return "STRING_A"
and running Code.EMPTY will return ""

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public enum Code {
    CODE_A,
    CODE_B,
    CODE_C,
    CODE_D,
    CODE_E,
    CODE_F,
    EMPTY("");
    final String name;
    Code(String name) { this.name = name; }
    Code() { this(null); }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name == null ? super.toString() : name;
    }
}
```

And

```
System.out.println("CODE_A=" + Code.CODE_A);
System.out.println("EMPTY=" + Code.EMPTY);
```

Result:

```
CODE_A=CODE_A
EMPTY=
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set an enum value to a string value?
It is incompatible so it will not work. Try this:

```
public class Main {
    public static class Code {
        public static final String CODE_A = "A";
        public static final String CODE_B = "B";
        public static final String CODE_C = "C";
        public static final String EMPTY = "";
    }

    private String Code;

    public void setCode (String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

If you now say:

```
setCode (Main.Code.EMPTY);
```

your variable 'code' of the 'Main' instance would be an empty string.

Comment: I have over 50 enum constants there, making all of them string doesnt looks a very good approach to me

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the empty string parameter from `EMPTY`, and then overriding `toString` like this:

```
public enum Code {
    CODE_A,
    CODE_B,
    CODE_C,
    CODE_D,
    CODE_E,
    CODE_F,
    EMPTY

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this == EMPTY ? "" : this.name();
    }
}
```

See also [`Enum.name()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--).