# Where is an error: in specification or codegen?

Tags: enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have swagger.json v2.0 with following declaration:

```
"SomeType": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
         "",
         "TYPE1",
         "TYPE2",
         "TYPE3"
     ]
},
```

When I use swagger-codegen (v2.2.1) to generate java code I get invalid enum (with "" as enum key and no value).

Swagger specification says, that enums should be follow JSON schema specification (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.5.1).

So, I want to understand, where is an error: in codegen or in specification or I miss something else.

Comment: As a test have you tried removing the empty value and see if that resolves the error?

Comment: @Peter4499 yep. It help as was expected. I understand, that the main problem is in enum declaration (do someone hear about enum with "" key???). My question is attempt to understand: should this situation be described in specification (there is no restriction for it) or this is should be solved in codegen.

Comment: Your enum definition is correct. The issue is with the codegen, you can report it on GitHub: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues. You can also try customizing the Mustache templates yourself to generate empty enum values as [`EMPTY("")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169031).